# How to update points in a plot live?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to update live a location of a picked point in the plot after picking the coordinate you want to move it, without needing to close my window.

I've searched for solutions and found the FuncAnimation option, but wasn't able to use it inside my code.

I've used PyQT5 to show a window so all the plot is inside a widget in the window.

```
import sys
from Entities import Soldier, CompanyCommander
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    soldiers = []
    picked_soldier = []

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('qt_designer.ui', self)

        s1 = Soldier(1, (3, 4), 100)
        s2 = Soldier(2, (5, 6), 100)
        s3 = Soldier(3, (1, 6), 100)
        s4 = Soldier(1, (2, 3), 100)
        s5 = Soldier(2, (3, 3.5), 100)
        s6 = Soldier(3, (4.2, 3.7), 100)
        s7 = Soldier(1, (5.3, 4), 100)
        s8 = Soldier(2, (2.6, 4.3), 100)
        s9 = Soldier(3, (7, 5.2), 100)

        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s1)
        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s2)
        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s3)
        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s4)
        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s5)
        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s6)
        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s7)
        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s8)
        MyWindow.soldiers.append(s9)


        add_points()


        self.plotWidget = FigureCanvas(MyWindow.fig)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.content_plot)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.plotWidget, self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.plotWidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.toolbar)

        MyWindow.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', MyWindow.on_pick)


    def on_pick(event):
        if len(MyWindow.picked_soldier) == 0:
            this_point = event.artist
            x_data = this_point.get_xdata()
            y_data = this_point.get_ydata()
            ind = event.ind
            index = -1

            for soldier in MyWindow.soldiers:
                if soldier.x == x_data and soldier.y == y_data:
                    index = soldier.ID - 1
                    MyWindow.picked_soldier.append(soldier)
                    break

            print(str(float(x_data[ind])) + ", " + str(float(y_data[ind])))
            print(str(MyWindow.soldiers[index].to_string()))

            MyWindow.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', MyWindow.on_click)
            MyWindow.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(MyWindow.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', MyWindow.on_pick))



    def on_click(event):
        x_data = event.xdata
        y_data = event.ydata

        if len(MyWindow.picked_soldier) > 0:
            soldier = MyWindow.picked_soldier.pop(0)
            soldier.update_location(x_data, y_data)
            print(soldier.get_location())

        print(x_data, y_data, len(MyWindow.picked_soldier))
        MyWindow.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', MyWindow.on_pick)
        MyWindow.fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(MyWindow.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', MyWindow.on_click))

    def soldier_index(x_data, y_data):
        for soldier in MyWindow.soldiers:
            if soldier.x == x_data and soldier.y == y_data:
                return soldier.ID - 1


def add_points():
    MyWindow.ax.clear()
    for s in MyWindow.soldiers:
        if s.companyNumber == 1:
            MyWindow.ax.plot(s.x, s.y, marker='o', markersize=5, color="blue", picker=5)

        elif s.companyNumber == 2:
            MyWindow.ax.plot(s.x, s.y, marker='o', markersize=5, color="red", picker=5)

        elif s.companyNumber == 3:
            MyWindow.ax.plot(s.x, s.y, marker='o', markersize=5, color="green", picker=5)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main()
```

I would like to find an option that will let me update the points on the plot live, or to know where and how to use the FuncAnimation option inside my code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm still learning matplotlib and have only used mayplotlib.pyplot, but if you can use it then here's a solution.

Pyplot.ion() turns on interactive plotting mode, which let's you interact with plots and renders them automatically, as opposed to waiting for you to call it to plot or anything.

Then, to change the position of a point or something, you set the relevant x or y or angle property to a new value using a set function. As far as I can tell, those set functions are not very standardized and some artist objects don't have all of them, but all those functions do is change the property value and set another artist property called artist.stale to be true, which tells the renderer to update them.

So, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplots as plot
plt.ion() #turns on interactive plotting
H, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,2]) #need comma to get handle to artist 
#instead of just plot object
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(H)
#here you should see the plot in the figure
H.set_xdata([1,2]) #update x values
#since plt.ion() has been called, the plot updates itself.
```